# Text box static value + text

Tags: c#, wpf

I want automatically add piece of plain text to my TextBox value. For example I want display statistics for John Latham, so it would be nice to have "Statistics for " added automatically then I assign Text property to my control. I did some research but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Could you please validate why? I guess it might be a reason because of Bindings, how can I achieve same results from code behind? Thanks!

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Name="imgStatistic" Source="/Images/Statistics.gif" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Width="50"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='Statistic for  {0}'}" Name="txtStatistics"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
    this.txtStatistics.Text = emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName;
```

Comment: StringFormat is applied along with the binding.  When you set the `Text` from code-behind, you're no longer using binding.

Comment: How to make it work from code behind?

Comment: What's wrong with another TextBlock containing "Statistics for"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Text="{Binding Title}"` means that it binds the value of the `Title` property of the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` to the `TextBox`'s `Text`.
That unwieldy sentence will say: You need an object that has a `Title` property and set it as the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` or one of its parents.

If you don't have such an object, Data Binding isn't for you.
Simply change your code to this:

```
this.txtStatistics.Text = string.Format("Statistic for {0} {1}",
                                        emp.FirstName, emp.LastName);
```

Comment: And that object, especially if just a POCO, would need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` right?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: If the text in the TextBox should get updated on changes to the property: Yes

Comment: OK, I just wanted to make sure I was right on my assumption of that. I missed that interface ***a lot*** when I first started down the path of data binding with WPF and Silverlight.